# How can you reserve space for an array without initializing each element?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

The following code will construct array of 10 Foo objects with default Foo constructor:

```
Foo foo[10];
```

but i don't want do this, i have havy foo constructor and later i will regenarate all foo objects one by one and assign
(copy) it to elements of foo array, so there is no sense 
to initialize array, i want just reserve space for it and set it elements later. Just like in the case of

```
int foo[10]
```

when elements of foo will not be initialized without ={}.
 How can i do this without using std namespace(i will use code both on PC and CUDA that isn't supports std)?

Comment: not able to use `std::vector`?

Comment: sounds more like an issue that you have a heave constructor, normally it is better to have a more lightweight constructor then have some other function to initialize it. that way errors in the construction can be handle better.

Comment: < not able to use std::vector? < i will use code both on PC and CUDA. CuDA doesn't shave support for std, it have it's one vectors but i prefer have same code both for CUDA a and PC

Comment: Does 'cuda vector' is compatible with `std::vector` ? if so, just use a `typedef` to use the "correct" vector of the platform...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do what all good dynamic containers do: separate memory allocation and object construction.

```
// allocate memory
char * space[10 * sizeof(Foo)];

// make sure it's aligned for our purposes
// see comments; this isn't actually specified to work
assert(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(space) % alignof(Foo) == 0);

// populate 4th and 7th slots
Foo * p = ::new (space + 3 * sizeof(Foo)) Foo('x', true, Blue);
Foo * q = ::new (space + 6 * sizeof(Foo)) Foo('x', true, Blue);

// ...

// clean up when done
q->~Foo();
p->~Foo();
```

---

The tricky part when using automatic storage is to get storage aligned at an address suitable for the alignment of the array element type. There are several ways to accomplish this; I'll elaboate on them in the future:

1. `std::align` (thanks to @Simple):

   ```
   char large_space[10 * sizeof(Foo) + 100];
   std::size_t len = sizeof large_space;
   void * space_ptr = large_space;

   Foo * space = static_cast<Foo *>(std::align(alignof(Foo), 10 * sizeof(Foo), space, len));
   assert(space != nullptr);

   // construct objects in &space[i]
   ```
2. Qualify the definition of `space` with `alignas`

   ```
   alignas(Foo) char space[10 * sizeof(Foo)];
   ```
3. Make `space` an array of a suitable specialization of `std::aligned_storage` (thanks to @RMF)

   ```
   std::aligned_storage<sizeof(Foo), alignof(Foo)>::type space[10];

   Foo *p = new (&space[3]) Foo('x', true, Blue);
   Foo *q = new (&space[6]) Foo('x', true, Blue);
   ```

Comment: Please, align your buffer!

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Err... yeah. Somehow :-(

Comment: In C++11 there is `std::aligned_storage` :)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Is that non-dynamic?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Neat! That'll be a lot more verbose, but it's cool. I'll add that!

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Wait, what about just using `alignas`?

Comment: That works too. It's also C++11, but has less compiler support :)

Comment: You can't use `static_cast<uintptr_t>(space) % alignof(Foo) == 0` portably to check for aligment AFAIK. You can cast a pointer to `std::uintptr_t` but the standards doesn't specify what the value of the resulting integer will be. You have to use `std::align`.

Comment: @Simple: It should be `reinterpret_cast`, but I think this is legit. `uintptr_t` is an integral type that can represent any object pointer. (But thank you for pointing out `std::align`!!)

Comment: @KerrekSB `reinterpret_cast` for a pointer to address 0x0001000 is allowed to produce 0x0001001, since it's possible to recover the original from that (the only guarantee you get from reinterpret_cast). So technically, it's not portable. In practice no implementation does such silliness, though.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: If that is allowed, how would you then even *define* what it means for storage to be aligned?

Comment: @KerrekSB you don't. The standard does (in terms of things you have no access or control over), and gives you facilities to obtain the proper alignments. (sadly it doesn't give you facilities to directly *check* the alignment, but you can do it by aligning and comparing with the original). You can simply describe pre- and post-conditions as "ptr is properly aligned for <whatever>", without any need to involve numbers or arithmetic.

Comment: For completeness, the standard basically says that alignment requirements dictate where an object of a given type can be allocated. It doesn't describe how those addresses are to be computed, though.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Makes sense. So basically you *couldn't* control alignment at all before C++11?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: 2/3 methods added; broken method 4 removed. It's weird that `std::align` is in the *dynamic* memory management library, since dynamic allocations are the only ones which actually come with builtin alignment guarantees and don't need any of this.

Comment: @KerrekSB yep, before C++11 you were stuck with platform-specific stuff (which fortunately was quite reliable because no one would implement such a crazy reinterpret_cast).

Comment: @bames53: Thanks for adding that! It was tedious and I was probably not going to do it :-)

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is by far to use `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<Foo> foo;
```

You can call `foo.reserve(10)` to allocate the memory, if needed. And if you have C++11, you can use `foo.emplace_back(/*args*/)` to create the objects directly into the array, no need to copy.

If you don't want to/ can't use `std::vector`, you can do it manually:

```
unsigned char foo[10 * sizeof(Foo)];
```

And then to construct the objects use the *placement new*:

```
int x = ...;
Foo *fooX = new (foo[x * sizeof(Foo)) Foo(/*args to the constructor*/);
```

But then you will have to call the destructors manually, eventually:

```
fooX->~Foo();
```

But note that this solution may have difficulties with the alignment of the byte array. You may prefer to use `malloc()` to be sure:

```
unsigned char *foo = malloc(10 * sizeof(Foo));
```

Comment: `unsigned char foo[10 * sizeof(Foo)];` doesn't guarantee the correct alignment. See the comments to Kerrek SB [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19678691/1137388) and wait for his promissed update.

Answer (score 2):

If you will not leaves holes in the array, you can simply use `std::vector` with `reserve` and `push_back`.

If you want holes in the array... You can obtain a properly sized and properly aligned chunk of memory with some allocator and then use placement-new and so on... But you will have to keep track of which holes are filled and which aren't anyway. `boost::optional` does all that already, so a `std::vector<boost::optional<Foo>>` would serve nicely and save you a bunch of trouble.

Answer (score 1):

The most simple way is to use `std::vector`

```
std::vector<Foo> foovec;
foovec.reserve(10);
```

So, there is place for 10 elements of type `Foo`, but they are not constructed yet.

Also, you can write something like this manually, using `placing-new`

```
char* place = static_cast<char*>(::operator new(sizeof(Foo) * 10));
```

And then fill with placement-new operator.

```
Foo* f1 = new (place) Foo(...);
Foo* f2 = new (place + sizeof(Foo)) Foo(...);
//
f1->~Foo();
f2->~Foo();
::operator delete(place);
```

Comment: How can i do this without using std namespace(i will use code both on PC and CUDA that isn't supports std)?

Comment: That's the obvious answer, but I think the idea here is to use automatic storage?!

Comment: CUDA doesn't support's std.. it have it's own vectors... but i prefer to use same code both on PC and CUDA cernel

Comment: As to the `std::vector` solution, *"So, there is place for 10 elements of type Foo, but they are not constructed yet."* - And you can't really construct only element 7 either. You can only do `push_back/emplace_back`s and `resize`s.

Answer (score 1):

My solution takes into consideration these constraints (implied by the OP and some comments to different answers):

1. We can't use the STL; and
2. We want to use stack memory (not the heap).

It also considers the alignment issues mentioned by others and, given that the OP was tagged C++11, we can use C++11.

First introduce storage for `Foo` that doesn't initialize it:

```
union FooStorage {

    Foo data;

    FooStorage() {
    }

    template <typename... Args>
    void init(Args&&... args) {
        new (&data) Foo{static_cast<Args&&>(args)...};
    }

    ~FooStorage() {
        data.~Foo();
    }
};
```

Notice that the constructor doesn't initialize `data` but the destructor destroys it. You **must** initialize `data` (using `init()`) before destruction. (From the OP, I assume it's going to happen but I have to point out this danger.)

Recal that initializations using `{ ... }` and `( ... )` are not equivalent. You must make a decision based on `Foo`'s constructors.

Allocate stack memory for 10 `Foo`s in this way

```
FooStorage buffer[10];
```

To initialize the `i`-th `Foo`:

```
buffer[i].init(/* constructor arguments */);
```

To use the `i`-th `Foo` by, say, calling it's method `do_something`:

```
buffer[i].data.do_something();
```

This is the basic idea. There a lot of improvements that can be done to `FooStorage`.

Answer (score -1):

Array of `boost::optional<Foo>` or C++14 `std::optional<Foo>`

```
boost::optional<Foo> foo[10];
```

?

Comment: The original poster does not have access to `std::vector`. What in the world makes you think he would have access to Boost or c++14?

Comment: `std::optional` was removed from C++14 anyway, and may be put into a TS so that its specification can settle down before adding it to C++17